# I don't understand why I have null MVC AJAX

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have Get and Post partial Action. Get take me a list of image which I have in ma app.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult ViewImageFileList()
{
    IEnumerable<string> allImages = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"));

    return PartialView(allImages);
}
```

Post delete image which I extra.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ViewImageFileList(string imageNameType)
{
    var fileToDeletePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"), imageNameType);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDeletePath))
    {
        fileOperations.Delete(fileToDeletePath);
    }

    return PartialView();
}
```

My .chhtml of my partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

<div class="name-block-style">
     Логотипы которые имеются
</div>

<div id=team-logo-wrapper-images>
<ul>
    @foreach (var fullPath in Model)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
        <li>
            <div class="box-name-image">

                <p class="image-name-type">@fileName</p>
                <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/{0}", fileName))"
                     class="logo-images" alt="Логотип команды"
                     title="Логотип команды" />
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

```
<div id="delete-image-form" class="form-group">
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "ViewImageFileList",
    "Team",
     new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "reloadPage()" }))
{
    <label>Введите имя с указание типа изображения</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-group" name="imageNameType" id="imageNameType" />
    <input type="submit" value="Удалить" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
</div>

<script>
    function reloadPage() {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

My problem is Null references when I write the deleting image and submit it(i do it by ajax). I have this error [Null reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8n4g.png) but when I click to continue, the image deleted and my script to reload page work.

I want to understand why I take the null and how I can fix it, because it stops my app always when I delete an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you POST after you delete the image you don't populate the model of the partial view, as you do correctly in `ViewImageFileList`. This has a result when the View Engine try to build the view that you would send after the POST to the client, to get a null reference exception when try to perform the `foreach` on a null reference.

That being said, the thing you need is to pass to the `PartialView` all the images. So just add before the `return` statement in the action method you POST this:

```
var allImages = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"));
return PatialView(allImages);
```

Comment: thank you i find my stupid mistake. Hovewer thank you , a make the same motion!

Answer (score 0):

When you browsing images you return view with model passed

```
return PartialView(allImages); //allImages is a model
```

But when you deleting images you return view without any model

```
return PartialView(); //need to pass a model
```

So after deleting you would like to redirect to `ViewImageFileList` to browse 
all images

```
[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult ViewImageFileList(string imageNameType)
{
    var fileToDeletePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"), imageNameType);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDeletePath))
    {
        fileOperations.Delete(fileToDeletePath);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ViewImageFileList");
}
```

or retrieve images in delete action once again and pass the list to view

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ViewImageFileList(string imageNameType)
{
    var fileToDeletePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"), imageNameType);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToDeletePath))
    {
        fileOperations.Delete(fileToDeletePath);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> allImages = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/"));

    return PartialView(allImages);
}
```

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("ViewImageFileList");` it can't work, your return type partial

Comment: @remk93 Yes, my mistake. You can just update returning type to `ActionResult` or `RedirectToRouteResult` to make it work. See updated answer.

Comment: better second case, because i have a script to reload the page, and not good idea redirect to partial view, because in partial view you doesn't have master page